# Firebase onWrite other instance event.params is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```js
exports.cloneUsers = functions.database.instance('ams4-contract').ref('/users/{user_id}').onWrite(event => {
//exports.cloneUsers = functions.database.ref('/users/{user_id}').onWrite(event => {
    let user_data = event.data.val();
    let user_id = event.params.user_id;

    console.log('event usr ' + event.timestamp);
    console.log('Indexing usr ' + user_id + ' ' + user_data);

    let elasticSearchFields = ['name', 'nick', 'martial art'];
    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'users/user/' + user_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = user_data ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        uri: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth: {
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password
        },
        body: _.pick(user_data, elasticSearchFields),
        json: true
    };

    return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
        console.log('Elasticsearch response', response);
    })

});
```

When I use `functions.database.ref`,
it can get `event.params.user_id`
and it can update elasticsearch complete.

But use `functions.database.instance('ams4-contract')`
`event.params.user_id` is undefined!

This log
log id 36608977830579 for `functions.database.ref`
log id 36604231411908 for `functions.database.instance('ams4-contract')`
Thank you.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug.  You can work around it for now by removing the leading slash from the ref string when you use instance():

```
exports.cloneUsers = functions.database.instance('ams4-contract')
    .ref('users/{user_id}')
```

I'm filing a bug internally with Firebase.  Feel free to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) on your own.